# iOS: How sync two UIScrollview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uipangesturerecognizer

I have two horizontal `UIScrollview`s. I want to synchronise their scrolling when user drag fingers in either of them. Here is my code:

```
self.topScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
self.topScrollView.delegate = self;
self.topScrollView.bounces = YES;

self.bottomScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
self.bottomScrollView.delegate = self;
self.bottomScrollView.bounces = YES;
...

- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if (scrollView == self.topScrollView)
    {
        self.bottomScrollView.delegate = nil;
    }
    else
    {
        self.topScrollView.delegate = nil;
    }
    ...
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate
{   
    ...
    self.topScrollView.delegate = self;
    self.bottomScrollView.delegate = self;
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    ...
    self.topScrollView.delegate = self;
    self.bottomScrollView.delegate = self;
}

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    // Sync the two scroll views
    if (scrollView == self.topScrollView)
    {
        [self.bottomScrollView setContentOffset:scrollView.contentOffset animated:NO];
    }
    else
    {
        [self.topScrollView setContentOffset:scrollView.contentOffset animated:NO];
    }
    ...
}
```

The two scroll views do scroll synchronously, however, the problem is all the bouncing and deceleration are gone. The whole scrolling movement becomes really rigid. If I remove all the syncing code, then each scroll view works just fine individually.
So, what is the problem? Or can `UIScrollView` not be synchronised?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `topScrollView.panGestureRecognizer` and `bottomScrollView.panGestureRecognizer` to take both gesture recognizers and add them to a common superview enclosing both scroll views.  Pan gestures on this superview would then be recognized by both children.

You'll most likely also need to be the delegate of both recognizers and let them be recognized simulaneously:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: I tried adding my controller as the delegate, but the assignment crashed with the following exception: '"UIScrollView's built-in pan gesture recognizer must have its scroll view as its delegate"

Comment: I guess I can always subclass scroll view and override the method. Cool I think this should work.

Answer (score 1):

I worked out the solution according to jszumski's answer. However, my situation is two vertical UIScrollViews side by side (scrollViewLeft and scrollViewRight). It should work for horizontal UIScrollViews without too much modification.

First, create a custom UIScrollView.

```
//.h file

@interface CSScrollView : UIScrollView

@end

//.m file

@implementation CSScrollView


-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer{

    return YES;

}

@end
```

Secondly, in your mainview,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];


    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.scrollViewLeft.panGestureRecognizer];

    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.scrollViewRight.panGestureRecognizer];

}
```

That's everything I need to set up two synchronized scrollviews. The real effect is much better than the regular way of sending/subscribing notifications in scrollview's scrollViewDidScroll and synchronize the contentOffset.

Answer (score 0):

@jszumski answer in Swift

1. Create a custom subclass of UIScrollView
2. Conform to `UIGestureRecognizer` delegate
3. Override the `gestureRecognizer(_:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith:)` `GestureRecognizerDelegate` method

```swift
public func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
```

4. Both collection views need to have the same superview. Add both gesture recognizers to your superview

```swift
yourSuperview.addGestureRecognizer(scrollView1.panGestureRecognizer)
yourSuperview.addGestureRecognizer(scrollView1)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hmm, what if the content size of one of the scroll views was dynamic?